# Knockout.js toJSON creating null objects from Breeze entities

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

Using Breeze and Knockout together so far without problems. But just run into some really odd behaviour.

It's going to be hard to reproduce or post code, but I'm going to ask the question anyway in the hope it rings a bell somewhere. Essentially the problem is that if I change or add an object in this particular instance, and then save, when I call ko.toJSON() on the entitiy, it replaces all the new/changed objects with null values.

The same serialisation code works fine for all the other objects so far, so it must be the entitiy itself which is somehow different. But looking at the objects, there's nothing obvious - although since knockout wraps everything in observables it'd be hard to spot anyway.

Apologies for the lack of information but I'm badly stumped - does this ring any bells for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you ever calling ko.toJSON?  Breeze automatically wraps and unwraps your entities for you when saving. Or is there some other reason, ( other than saving), for calling ko.toJSON?

Comment: We started out doing it manually to get greater control, and followed that pattern although it's not necessary in a lot of cases. It probably isn't here and I'm currently experimenting with using the native saveChanges() - but am getting a "this[propertyName] is not a function" error. Which bought me back to SO :)

Comment: Can you show some code or send a simple example to breeze@ideablade.com?

Comment: Really appreciate you're help, but I can't really send the whole project, and it'd be too much work to cut out the relevant bits. Trying the out of the box SaveChanges at the moment but getting all sorts of odd errors - nasty feeling I've dug myself into an overcomplex hole.